# Ionic ion-nav-buttons size and style

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to make ionic navigation buttons with full size of header height.
I want to get this

[image]

But with below I am getting this one, not quite right: First one button fills the header height, but second one, button stays padded inside header (note: header background is white).

[image]

html

```
  <ion-nav-buttons side="left" >
    <button class="icon button-custom ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
    </button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
```

css

```
.button-custom,
.button-custom.icon:before{
  font-size: 34px !important;
  border-style: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ed4949;
  color: white;
}
```

Is it possible to make second image style same as first one?

Comment: are u using any framework?

Comment: As far i see, padding has been given 0px, that is fine

Comment: Do one thing, give a space between .button-custom and .icon:before

Comment: Thanks, I think I solved the issue, but I don't think this is solution

Answer (score 0):

Well changing css to:

```
.button-custom,
.button-custom.icon:before{
  font-size: 34px !important;
  border-style: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  background-color: #ed4949;
  color: white;
}
.button-custom {
    margin: -5px 0 -5px -5px!important;
}
```

Seem to fix it, but perhaps there is better way of doing it?! For future reference I will leave it here, if it helps anyone...

Comment: Did you get what u wanted?